# How to keep all digits when parsing a json string to map

Tags: java, json, digits

I got a json string like this

```
{
"ParValue":100.00,
"RealAmount":100.00,
"SettlementAmt":86.000,
"CardNo":"1707264632031051",
"ReturnCode":1,
"ReturnMsg":"success",
"PlatformOrderNo":"OR1903121512045682711",
"MerchOrderNo":"163244040",
"Sign":"9A9B363CBDABBF14C1F8EFC34CC09D2E"
}
```

and I want to transform that to a Map object ,so I used this way:

```
   HashMap<String,String> map=new Gson().fromJson(response,HashMap.class);
```

or this

```
HashMap<String,String> map=  new ObjectMapper().readValue(response,HashMap.class);
```

(response is represent the above json string.)

After that I got a map [image]

all digits has been trimed,I need to keep the origin value, is there any way to do that?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean: `100.00 == 100.0 == 100.000000000000000000000000000`

Comment: It's a number, there is no point in even trying to do that

Comment: if you have 100.04, the precision will be retained

Comment: @Lino  I have to use orgin params to check if the sign is correct or not. And  the  sign I got here is generated from theses params .

Answer (score 1):

Because `ParValue`, `RealAmount` and `SettlementAmt` is JSON number type.

you need to convert all to string type before using `Gson`:

```
{
    "ParValue":"100.00",
    "RealAmount":"100.00",
    "SettlementAmt":"86.000",
    "CardNo":"1707264632031051",
    "ReturnCode":1,
    "ReturnMsg":"success",
    "PlatformOrderNo":"OR1903121512045682711",
    "MerchOrderNo":"163244040",
    "Sign":"9A9B363CBDABBF14C1F8EFC34CC09D2E"
}
```

Hope that help you.